# How to omit GOPATH for visual code GO plugin

Tags: visual-studio, go

I'm using the visual code and GO plugin.

I configured the verbose option for go test `"go.testFlags": ["-v"]`.

In this case, when I run the test unit, from the output window, I'm seeing the full path of the test unit.

```
--- PASS: TestConstantBinary (0.00s)
    /Users/ian.w/Documents/learngo/src/learnGO/tests/constant_test.go:27: true false false
```

Is that possible to omit the GOPATH from the above,

`GOPATH=/Users/ian.w/Documents/learngo`

Thanks a lot.

Comment: so if i understand you properly you have verbose testing active but you do not want verbose output?

Comment: @Pizzalord I want the results show up, not the path to the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to strip of  GOPATH from the output. Test output will always use the `absolute` path